# React router - views with dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In my application, there are views with dependencies. For example, in one view a user could select an item from a list (generated on the server), and in next view the user would perform operations on the item. The item is passed to the second view in props. I'm moving to using react router, but there are some difficulties:

- I can't use props for transferring data anymore. What would be a preferred way to pass data? Do I have to use redux?
- Users can navigate from any view to any other view by directly using url. However, some transitions don't make sense: e.g. user navigates to item editing view from somewhere else, and therefore does not have an item selected. Is there a way to limit allowed transitions?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question, but I'll take a stab at it.

Can you use Redux?  Sure, Redux is good for centralizing your state which can easily be shared among your components.   As far as limiting the url's they have access to, I would use your reducer to look at your current state, if you're using Redux and if data is not there, meaning they should not be at this step, use a javascript redirect to where they should be instead.

Finally, you don't have to use Redux to share data between components this could be done by setting global variables your components can access, but cross component communication is where Redux shines.